# Read ints recusively from file into array, the second last element always wrong

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int fillArray(ifstream& ifs, int array[]){
    int cur;
    int counter = 0;

    if(ifs>>cur){
        counter = fillArray(ifs, array) + 1;
        array[counter-1] = cur;
    }

    return counter;
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int count;
    int array[] = {0};
    ifstream myfile ("/Users/Desktop/example.txt");


    count = fillArray(myfile, array);

    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }

    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

For example, if the input file is "1 2 3 100 19 16 33", the resulted array is "33 7 19 100 3 2 1".
if the input file is"1 2 3 4 5", the array will be "5 5 3 2 1". 
I don't mind ints are filled in reversely, but I don't understand what happened to the second last ints.

And this code works fine in VS, it only has problem in xcode.

Comment: `array`, declared in main, is of size `1`. This means that reading beyond index zero, as you are doing, is _undefined behavior_ which is likely why it behaves differently on different compilers. You should declare the array either with a large static size or a dynamic size, or use a vector.

Comment: I'm wondering what's the point of using _recursion_ here.

Comment: Using recursion to read a file could readily run you into a stack overflow with large files, but for small files, I think recursion is a healthy thinking exercise for a learning programmer, if admittedly not the most efficient approach.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it was an recursion exercise.

Comment: @TimStraubinger thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code only "works fine in VS" by accident. It creates an array with one element, then stores past the end of the array, so it's deep into undefined behavior. Instead of a hard-coded array, use `std::vector<int>`; that will let you add as many elements as are needed. Each time you get a new element you can call `push_back` to put it into the vector.